# International Resource Identifier Validation

Tags: php, validation

Validating URIs for RFC 3986 is fairly simple. You can use a [regular expression like](http://mattfarina.com/2009/01/08/rfc-3986-url-validation):

```
/^                                                     # Start at the beginning of the text
([a-z][a-z0-9\*\-\.]*):\/\/                            # The scheme
(?:                                                    # Userinfo (optional)                                              
  (?:(?:[\w\.\-\+!$&'\(\)*\+,;=]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+:)*
  (?:[\w\.\-\+%!$&'\(\)*\+,;=]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+@
)?
(?:                                                    # The domain
  (?:[a-z0-9\-\.]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+                       # Domain name or IPv4
  |(?:\[(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4}:)*(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4})\])        # or IPv6
)
(?::[0-9]+)?                                           # Server port number (optional)
(?:[\/|\?]
  (?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&@!$'~*,;\/\(\)\[\]\-]|%[0-9a-f]{2}) # The path (optional) 
*)?
$/xi
```

But, this doesn't work for International characters like those found in International Domain Names. For example,[http://例え.テスト/メインページ](http://%E4%BE%8B%E3%81%88.%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8).

Using something like

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED);
```

doesn't work for these either. The issue has to do with the characters used.

Is there a good way to validate URIs in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

With preg_match \pL will match any unicode letter. So replace the a-z with \pL. And 0-9 with \pN. See [Regular Expression Details](http://au.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php#regexp.reference.unicode) for more information.